# Promises jumping too fast to then() (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with promises. The point is that the one function isn't completed and the executing code is jumping to `then` method.

```js
const load = (function() {
  const site = function(url, parent) {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        return response.text()
      })
      .then(data => {
        parent.innerHTML = data;
      })
  };

  return {
    site: site,
  };
})();

function mainApp() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(document.querySelector('.content'));
      const welcome = document.createElement('div');
      const content = document.querySelector('.content');
      welcome.textContent = `Welcome, ${user.displayName}`;
      content.appendChild(welcome);
    } else {

    }
  });
}

function promise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, rejected) => {
    load.site('pages/main/main.html', content);
    //this function isn't completed and executing code is jumping to then
  })
}

promise().then(() => {
  console.log('then');
  mainApp(); //this function is called before the upper code is completed
});
```

And because of this bug I can't change the DOM in mainApp function because this function is completed before the load function (which is also changing to DOM by using fetch). My goal is to firstly call and complete `load.site()` and then `mainApp()` but I don't know what's happening now and where is the problem.

Comment: The promise is never resolved or rejected.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. `mainApp` is never called: https://jsfiddle.net/xdugqtmL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you assumed that we assume that you resolved the function like

```js
function promise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, rejected) => {
    load.site('pages/main/main.html', content);
    resolve(); // Like this.
  })
}
```

#### The Problem

When you call `promise`. It calls `load.site` and then resolves. So why isn't it giving the expected behavior.
Well, **the problem is that `load.site` is a synchronous function, so it does not wait for the `fetch` call and returns** which resolves `promise` before `fetch` is resolved. So, the code in `promise.then()` runs before the code in `fetch.then()`

#### The Solution

Make `load.site` an asynchronous function so that it returns a promise that can be awaited. i.e.

```js
const site = async function (url) {
        return fetch('a.js')
        .then(response =>{
            return response.text()
        })
        .then(data =>{
            console.log("Loaded");
        })
};
```

Then make the `promise`'s executor async so that you await `load.site`. i.e.

```js
function promise() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, rejected) => {
        await load.site('pages/main/main.html'); // This line does the magic
        resolve();
    });
};
```

This will make sure that your `promise` resolves **after** `fetch` has resolved. So that you can get the expected behavior.

Hope it helps. **Keep on coding**